# Unable To Cast Window to WPFWindows

Tags: wpf, casting, window

I am using white for the wpf automation testing .. when I use Application.getWindow() it returns me Core.UIItems.WindowItems.window . but when I try to cast it to Core.UIItems.WindowItems.WPFWindow on runtime it "Unable to cast exception" is thrown. though WPFWindow inherits Window this fails... Help me.... Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please post the full exception text

Answer (score 0):

I don't know white very well. I'm using [guia](http://guia.codeplex.com) to test my WPF user interfaces though.
Maybe you can give it a shot.